# Merging Queues in Java

Tags: java, queue

I have my own ArrayQueue Class which has methods for `enqueue`, `dequeue` and `peek` etc. My `ArrayQmerge` class extends this Class and contains:

```
    public void mergeQs(ArrayQmerge q){

    }
```

I was wondering whats the best way to write a method to merge an ArrayQueue with another Queue without removing any elements from the q thats passed.

eg. `queue1 = [1,2,3,4,11]` and `queue2 = [5,6,7,8,9,10,12]`.
When `queue1.mergeQs(queue2)` is called it will create `queue1 = [1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8,11,9,10,12]` whilst `queue2` would remain `[5,6,7,8,9,10,12]`

I want the `mergeQs` method to interleave the elements from the two queues if that makes sense. I know how to successfully add them together or using a method which passes both Queues as arguments but in this case i want to use the above method(which only passes one)...

Comment: You haven't shown any of the internal workings, so how are we supposed to help? This is not possible with just the basic queue API.

Comment: It sounds like you solved your problem with the ArrayQmerge class. What is wrong with that solution?

Comment: What other information do you need? 
I just need help writing the actual method that will take `Queue2`'s element at index 0 and place it into `Queue1`'s index 1 using the above method `public void mergeQs(ArrayQmerge q){}` I do not know how to do this with only passing the one argument...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayQmerge q1 = new ArrayQmerge();
    q1.enqueue(1);
    q1.enqueue(2);
    q1.enqueue(3);
    q1.enqueue(4);
    q1.enqueue(11);
    ArrayQmerge q2 = new ArrayQmerge();
    q2.enqueue(5);
    q2.enqueue(6);
    q2.enqueue(7);
    q2.enqueue(8);
    q2.enqueue(9);
    q2.enqueue(10);
    q2.enqueue(12);
    System.out.println(q1);
    System.out.println(q2);
    q1.mergeQs(q2);
    System.out.println(q1);
    System.out.println(q2);
}

static class ArrayQmerge{
    private List<Integer> queue = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void enqueue(int val){
        queue.add(val);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return queue.toString();
    }

    public void mergeQs(ArrayQmerge q){
        List<Integer> mergedQ = new ArrayList<Integer>(this.queue.size() + q.queue.size());
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < this.queue.size() || j < q.queue.size();){
            if (i < this.queue.size())
                mergedQ.add(this.queue.get(i++));
            if (j < q.queue.size())
                mergedQ.add(q.queue.get(j++));
        }
        this.queue = mergedQ;
   }
}
```

Here is output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 11]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12]
[1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 11, 9, 10, 12]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12]
```

Comment: This is really cool. Does exactly what i wanted. Is there a way to implement it if the ArrayQueues were created like this: `ArrayQmerge queue1 = new ArrayQmerge();` and added to like this: `queue1.enqueue("1");` `queue1.enqueue("2");` `queue1.enqueue("3");`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can merge q1 + q2 => q3 interleaving elements:

```
    Queue<Integer> q1 = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,11));
    Queue<Integer> q2 = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(5,6,7,8,9,10,12));
    Queue<Integer> q3 = new ArrayDeque<>();
    Iterator<Integer> i1 = q1.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> i2 = q2.iterator();
    for(;;) {
        if (i1.hasNext()) {
            q3.add(i1.next());
        }
        if (i2.hasNext()) {
            q3.add(i2.next());
        }
        if (!i1.hasNext() && !i2.hasNext()) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(q3);
```

Note: new ArrayDeque<> is Java 7 feature

Comment: Thats nice code, but ideally i want to merge `queue2` into `queue1` without creating a new `Queue`. So `queue1` contains all elements by calling `.mergeQs` using: `queue1.mergeQs(queue2)`